# Sum values in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g, sum

I'm trying to do a homework problem that requires.

```
--5. CALCULATE THE TOTAL QUANTITY ON HAND FOR EACH INVENTORY IT IN THE INVENTORY
--TABLE-IGNORE THIER DIFFERNT SIZES AND COLORS
```

This is the query I've come with. I looks right except for the qoh value

```
SELECT DISTINCT(item.item_id),item.item_desc,
(SELECT SUM(inv_qoh) FROM INVENTORY WHERE i.item_id = item.item_id)
FROM ITEM item INNER JOIN INVENTORY i ON i.item_id = item.item_id;
```

Each rows returns 3143 instead of the value for that specific item_id.

```
     5 Children's Beachcomber Sandals                                                         3143 
     7 Girl's Soccer Tee                                                                      3143 
     4 Women's Fleece Pullover                                                                3143 
     6 Boy's Surf Shorts                                                                      3143 
     1 Men's Expedition Parka                                                                 3143 
     3 Women's Hiking Shorts                                                                  3143 
     2 3-Season Tent                                                                          3143
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want to use something like this.  It applies the `sum()` aggregate and a `GROUP BY` to the remaining two fields in your `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT item.item_id, 
    item.item_desc,
    SUM(i.inv_qoh) TotalInventory
FROM ITEM item 
INNER JOIN INVENTORY i 
    ON item.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY item.item_id, item.item_desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this in a bit of a roundabout manner, but it should work if you make the following correction:

---

Take a look at the subquery in your select clause:

```
SELECT SUM(inv_qoh) FROM INVENTORY WHERE i.item_id = item.item_id
```

You're using the aliases `i` and `item` in the where clause, but neither of those correspond to the table you're selecting from. To correct this, you need to add a third alias for that table and reference it:

```
SELECT SUM(inv_qoh) FROM INVENTORY i2 WHERE i2.item_id = item.item_id
```

You may notice at this point that you're not actually using anything from `inventory` in your outer SQL statement, so you can remove it all together (which would also allow you to eliminate the `distinct`).

---

That said, @bluefeet's answer should give you the same result in a much more effective manner.

Comment: Thanks I like both of your answers